# Does the temperature of the water, while taking a shower after cardio, matters?

Tags: cardio

I'm remailn skeptical to a comment of a collegue, who claims that after making some cardio training, water temperature while taking a shower immediately after training prevents you from keeping burning calories.

Is there any reason not to consider this nonsense?

Comment: No reason to consider it legit.  At most you are talking maybe 10 Calories difference in a day (being generous).  That's not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your friend is over-thinking it.  According to [this study](http://www.fastexercise.com/?LP=70), there are several factors that contribute to continued burning of calories after exercise, one of which is:

> Decrease in Body Temperature: As energy is liberated from the
>   exercising muscle tissues of the body, heat is produced. Thus, during
>   EPOC, the body must expend energy to return to the normal core body
>   temperature.

So theoretically, if you are taking a hot shower, you are actually causing your body to work harder to get back down to the normal core temp, which should result in more calories burned.  Taking a cold shower should have the opposite effect.  If you consider that your body should be back to normal temp about 20 minutes after your workout anyways, and assuming you are cooling down normally (walking for 5 - 10 minutes after your workout), the differences in calories burned wouldn't be noticeable based on the temperature of your shower.

Answer (score 2):

Prevents you from burning calories? I certainly haven't heard anything like that. I suppose their theory is that if your core temperature remains higher, your heart rate will also remain higher? Or are they saying that by taking a cold shower your body has to work harder to regain that body temp?

Either way, I have a hard time believing that the temperature of your shower drastically impacts the amount of calories you burn either way.